# Data should retain in kendo-grid when page is reload if local storage is a solution how to use it in my code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

This is the Html file to create a user by user-input and showing data on kendo-Grid

```
<html>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dialog/predefined-dialogs">
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="aza.js"></script>
    <link href="kendo.html">
    <link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <h3> ADD USER</h3>
    <dl>
        <dt>FirstName</dt>
        <dd>
            <input type="text" id="inputtext3">
        </dd>
        <dt>LastName</dt>
        <dd>
            <input type="text" id="inputtext4">
        </dd>
        <dt>Age</dt>
        <dd>
            <input type="text" id="inputtext5">
        </dd>
        <dd>
            <button id="add"> Create </button>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <div id="grid">
        <table id="weapons">
            <tr>
                <th data-field="firstname">FirstName</th>

                <th data-field="lastname">LastName</th>

                <th data-field="age">Age</td>

            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>

    </html>
```

Now Below is JS file- This is Binding the data to kendo-grid but i want to retain data after reloading the page which is not happening right now

```
app.controller('aza', function() {
    $(function() {    
        var Weapon = kendo.data.Model.define({    
            id: "firstname"
        })
        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                   dataType: "json"
                } ,
                create : {
                   dataType: "json",type: "POST"
                } 
            },
            pageable: {
                refresh : true
            },
            schema : {
                model : Weapon
            }
        });
        $("#weapons").kendoGrid({    
            dataSource : dataSource
        });

        $("#add").click(function(){
            dataSource.add({  
               firstname : $("#inputtext3").val(),
               lastname: $("#inputtext4").val(),
               age: $("#inputtext5").val() 
            });
            dataSource.sync();
            $("#inputtext3").val('');
            $("#inputtext4").val('');
            $("#inputtext5").val('');
            $('#weapons').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();     
            $('#weapons').data('kendoGrid').refresh(); 
        })
    });
});
```

I tried local Storage  but didn't work Please assist..I need a solution to retain my data on kendo-grid

Comment: What is your question?  You provided three statements and two code snippets without asking anything.  We cannot help you if you do not explain what is wrong, what you tried, and what you are referring to exactly.

Comment: @Jedi_Maseter_Sam I want to retain my data after page reload

Comment: can u add what u tried with localStorage as can't see any in the code regarding that